# Javascript method gives nul value when dynamically choose the selector value

Tags: javascript

Using javascript to create the selector value dynamically, i tried to create the following code:

```
function generateButton() {

    var Period = "Period";

    function add(selText, selID) {
        var sel = document.getElementById(selID);
        console.log(sel);
        var selValue = sel.value;
        return selText + selValue;
    }

    var x = add("Period: ", Period + "---");
}



 <select id="Period" name="Period" data-val-required="The Period field is required." data-val="true">



<button type="submit" onclick="generateButton()">Generate</button>
```

But getting null of sel value. Did i miss something here?

Comment: you have an element with Period--- as id?

Comment: Just check whether you are getting proper value of selID or not.

Comment: Yes, i have that id. it looks:   <select id="Period" name="Period" data-val-required="The Period field is required." data-val="true">

Comment: what is that suffix `... + "---"` for ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  i need to format the output and need to feed that x value to other part of the code

Comment: Your add function is looking for an element with id "Period---". Do you have that in your page?

Comment: @Hector Barbossa, Yes, i have

Comment: Why are you appending `---` to the ID that you're looking for?

Comment: @adarksun You have `id="Period"`, you don't have `id="Period---"`.

Comment: @adarksun it seems you have an element with id "Period" but your function is looking for "Period---"

Comment: Got it. that is wrong. Thanks. now i deleted that and its working. :)